# /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: debian, dpkg

After trying to install an `openvpn` I've got this:

[image]

`apt-get` became broken - unable to install/purge anything. I've got 2 versions of python install 2.7.1 and 3 (wondering if this could cause the conflict).

EDIT: just to confirm `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/` has apt_pkg.co, while neither `python3` nor `python3.2` has. May be there is a way to fix it.

Comment: Please paste text as text, not an image. Thanks. Also, please paste the output of `apt-get -f install`. Also, do you have any packages installed locally? And do you have a mixed system? That's often the cause of errors. If so, paste the output of `apt-cache policy`.

Comment: Please specify your system too. ARM? Raspberry?

Comment: Thank you for help, I've posted the answer. The solution is not connected to the things you've asked - it was due to Python3 usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the logs and some thinking I've found the source of the problem. I was following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-apache-mysql-and-python-lamp-server-without-frameworks-on-ubuntu-14-04) to setup a LAMP-server. What a "nice" idea from author to remove `/usr/bin/python` and create new link to Python3 `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3`!!

To bad this spoiled Package Management tool.

Solution:

1. Remove the link again
2. Create symlink to Python 2.7 back
3. Profit!